# User Folder/Desktop path getting reset after Windows Explorer crashed

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, user-profiles

So my laptop was screwy this morning, mozy Home backup froze up and when tryign to kill the process, Windows Explorer crashed along with it.  Windows 7 tried to do its normal recover, which went ok, but it was still sluggish, so i decided to do a reboot.

When I log back in to my local account, it was as if I created an all new account.  The wallpaper, start menu, icons, etc were all back to the windows defaults.  I paniced thinking all the stuff on my desktop was gone.

I located all my stuff in C:\Users\Neil\Desktop ...

I confirmed that I was indeed logged in to the same account, so what wasnt it showing?  I created a folder on my new blank desktop, opened it to check the full path.  It now points to: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop\

How do I reset the user folder path to where all my stuff is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your profile got damaged and the system's default profile was loaded instead. Use this tutorial to check whether your profile path is correct: http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/05/how-to-change-user-profile-default-location-in-windows-7/ (Take a look at step 3)

Comment: Yep, just found that same site, fixed the registry key, and my profile is now back to the correct folder, thanks!

Comment: @NeilN Good it worked for you! :D

Comment: And that link is dead. This is why you should always write the important content in the answer itself.